# We have $ f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(x-1)^n}{n}$ prove that $f(x) = -\ln(2-x)$.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, derivatives, power-series

I am having problems with the following exercise, I have solved the first two parts of the exercise but I am unsure about the last part.

I have the following power series

$$f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{(x-1)^n}{n}$$

$\large 1. $ Find the convergence interval.

I start out by finding the radius of convergence. I let $a_n = 1/n$

$$ r = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right| = 1$$

And then I evaluate the endpoints and get the results that $\sum_{n \geq 1} = \dfrac{(x-1)^n}{n}$ converges when $x \in [0,2)$.

$\large 2. $ Show that $f'(x) = 1/(2-x)$ at all points where f converges absolutely. 
From the previous exercise I know that $f$ converges absolutely when $\vert x-1 \vert < 1$. I also have that

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \dfrac{n(x-1)^{n-1}}{n} = \sum_{n \geq 1}(x-1)^{n-1} = \sum_{n \geq 0}(x-1)^{n}$$

By using the geometric series formula I have that

$$\sum_{n \geq 0}(x-1)^{n} = \dfrac{1}{1-(x-1)} = \dfrac{1}{2-x}.$$

$3. $ Prove that $f(x) = -ln(2-x)$ on the convergence interval. (hint: use the fundamental theorem of calculus)

This is my approach:

I have from the previous exercise that $f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{2-x}$ thus I must have that

\begin{align*}
f(x) =& \int f'(x) dx\\
= & \int \dfrac{1}{2-x} dx \\
= & - \int \dfrac{1}{u} du, ~~~~\text{where}~~u=2-x,~\text{thus}~~dx=-du\\
=& -\ln(u)\\
=& - \ln(2-x)~~~\text{by substittuting back.}
\end{align*}

Is my approach correct? Is there something I have forgotten to do?

Best regards

Husky

Comment: There is something missing here. You integrated back using an indefinite integral but you need a constant somewhere. That is $f(x)=- \ln (2-x) +c$ You also need to determine that constant. But that is easy since for $x=0$ we get that:

$$f(0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = -\ln 2$$

hence $c=0$ and over. In general there is nothing wrong with your approach except fot that.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you very much !